# Como obtener valor de un <Select> en contenteditable y mantener valor

Tags: html

Hola estoy adaptando un codigo y necesito su ayuda....

lo que necesito  es que a travez de un select obtener un valor  y que este se muestra en la celda editable (item_mes)y al agregar otra fila para insertar datos se mantenga ese valor en la celda editable(item_mes)

```html
<head>
  <title>hi</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">hello</h2>
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="crud_table">

      <tr>
        <select name="meses">
        <option value="enero">Enero</option>
  <option value="febrero">Febrero</option>
  <option value="marzo">Marzo</option>
  <option value="abril">Abril</option>
</select>
</tr>
     <tr>
      <th width="30%">Item Name</th>
      <th width="10%">Item Code</th>
      <th width="45%">Item_Mes</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="item_name"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="item_code"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="item_mes"></td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <div align="right">
     <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">+</button>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
     <button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="inserted_item_data"></div>
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var count = 1;
 $('#add').click(function(){
  count = count + 1;
  var html_code = "<tr id='row"+count+"'>";
   html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_name'></td>";
   html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_code'></td>";
   html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_mes'></td>";
   html_code += "<td><button type='button' name='remove' data-row='row"+count+"' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs remove'>-</button></td>";   
   html_code += "</tr>";  
   $('#crud_table').append(html_code);
 });
 
 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  var delete_row = $(this).data("row");
  $('#' + delete_row).remove();
 });
 
 $('#save').click(function(){
  var item_name = [];
  var item_code = [];
  var item_mes = [];
  $('.item_name').each(function(){
   item_name.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_code').each(function(){
   item_code.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_mes').each(function(){
   item_desc.push($(this).text());
  });
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{item_name:item_name, item_code:item_code, item_mes:item_mes },
   success:function(data){
    alert(data);
    $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
    for(var i=2; i<= count; i++)
    {
     $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
    }
    fetch_item_data();
   }
  });
 });
 
 function fetch_item_data()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#inserted_item_data').html(data);
   }
  })
 }
 fetch_item_data();
 
});
</script>
```

Comment: El código compartido no tiene ningún `<select>`, ¿te refieres a las celdas con contenido editable? Parece que sí, pero no termina de quedar claro y no es lo que se indica en el título o el cuerpo de la pregunta. Y para continuar, ¿qué valor debe mantenerse cuando se pulsa en el `+`? ¿El de la primera fila o el de la última fila?

Comment: ya lo edite....

Comment: Ok. Entonces quieres que el valor del `<select>` se mantenga... ¿dónde? Porque si le doy al `+` el `select` no cambia, por lo que el valor se mantiene. ¿Quieres ponerlo en una de las celdas? ¿o tienes otro código que afecta al `select` y resetea el valor? Por favor, pon una descripción más específica del fallo, porque tal y como está ahora no se entiende o no se puede reproducir el problema.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro necesito que el valor de el <select> se agregue en la celda con contenido editable y al precionar + se mantenga ese valor en la nueva fila

Comment: Tienes 3 celdas con contenido editable, ¿a cuál de ellas? (Supongo que item_mes, pero no lo indicas). Y cuando se presiona el +, ¿quieres que se mantenga el valor de la fila anterior o el del <select> (que puede haber cambiado)?

Comment: Perdón si soy pesado con las preguntas, pero es que a esta publicación le falta información básica para poder ayudarte.

Comment: disculpa por no explicar bien ,quiero que al eleccionar una opcion del  <select> se muestre en la celda del contenido editable (item_mes) y al darle click en "+" se mantenga el valor de item_mes en todas las nuevas filas que cree con el boton + (es decir ese valor siempre se mostrara en las celda item_mes cada vez que se cree una nueva fila)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de leer la pregunta, entiendo que quieres que toda nueva fila que se cree tenga en su columna Item_mes el valor del mes. Para realizar esto, tan solo hay que añadir al evento onclick del botón que se inserte el valor (atributo value) seleccionado:

```
html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_mes'>" + $('#comboMeses option:selected').val() + "</td>";
```

Si en lugar del atributo value deseas añadir el texto en el innerHTML de la opción, en su lugar usa:

```
html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_mes'>" + $('#comboMeses option:selected').html() + "</td>";
```

El código quedaría así:

```html
<head>
  <title>hi</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">hello</h2>
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="crud_table">

      <tr>
        <select id="comboMeses" name="meses">
          <option value="enero">Enero</option>
          <option value="febrero">Febrero</option>
          <option value="marzo">Marzo</option>
          <option value="abril">Abril</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">+</button>
</tr>
     <tr>
      <th width="30%">Item Name</th>
      <th width="10%">Item Code</th>
      <th width="45%">Item_Mes</th>
      <th></th>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="inserted_item_data"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
     <button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var count = 1;
 $('#add').click(function(){
  count = count + 1;
  var html_code = "<tr id='row"+count+"'>";
   html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_name'></td>";
   html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_code'></td>";
   html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_mes'>" + $('#comboMeses option:selected').val() + "</td>";
   html_code += "<td><button type='button' name='remove' data-row='row"+count+"' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs remove'>-</button></td>";   
   html_code += "</tr>";  
   $('#crud_table').append(html_code);
 });
 
 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  var delete_row = $(this).data("row");
  $('#' + delete_row).remove();
 });
 
 $('#save').click(function(){
  var item_name = [];
  var item_code = [];
  var item_mes = [];
  $('.item_name').each(function(){
   item_name.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_code').each(function(){
   item_code.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.item_mes').each(function(){
   item_desc.push($(this).text());
  });
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{item_name:item_name, item_code:item_code, item_mes:item_mes },
   success:function(data){
    alert(data);
    $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
    for(var i=2; i<= count; i++)
    {
     $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
    }
    fetch_item_data();
   }
  });
 });
 
 function fetch_item_data()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#inserted_item_data').html(data);
   }
  })
 }
 fetch_item_data();
 
});
</script>
```

Sin embargo, no puedo evitar resaltar un par de cambios que yo haría:

1. Tu cabecera tiene 3 columnas pero el resto de filas tienen cuatro, por lo que la cabecera no tiene borde derecho. ¿Es éste el comportamiento esperado? Considera añadir un colspan si quieres que una columna ocupe el equivalente a más columnas o añadir otro th.
2. Construyes la fila con una cadena de texto e insertas ese texto en el innerHTML. Afortunadamente los navegadores optimizan estás concatenaciones de texto, así que no hay problemas de rendimiento (y aunque los hubiera, si tu cadena ocupa menos de 200 caracteres no vas a notar la diferencia). Sin embargo, si estás usando JQuery a mí me gusta más (y esto es solo mi opinión) ir construyendo el objeto con las funciones de JQuery.

Sería algo como lo siguiente:

```
var $fila = $('<tr></tr>')
    .attr('id', 'row' + count)
    .append(
        $('<td></td>')
            .attr('contenteditable', 'true')
        ...
    )
    ...
```

De esta forma cuando quieras hacer cambios puedes trabajar sobre elementos de JQuery que has ido creando, con todas las facilidades que te da JQuery en lugar de cambiar una cadena de texto, algo que se hace inmanejable conforme se incrementa la complejidad de los elementos que creas.

Como te digo, esto último es solo una opinión.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: funciona excelente.
me podrias ayudar en algo mas....
agregue  un boton (+) junto al select y necesito que no se muestre primera fila, si no que aparezca al clickear el boton (+) ,te lo agradecia mucho

Comment: De acuerdo, ahora lo edito :). Si crees que la respuesta te sirvió puedes marcarla como correcta

Comment: Hola @outsider, ya está editado.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda ,funciono perfecto

Comment: disculpa la molestia de nuevo.. 
te queria preguntar como hacer lo mismo del select 
con un input
codigo: 

html += '<td><input type="text"  name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name" /></td>';

Comment: Hola @outsider, lo siento pero no termino de entender a qué te refieres. ¿Podrías detallarlo un poco más?

Comment: pues lo de obtener el valor de select en un input pero ya lo solucione, al parecer solo era colocar el codigo que me proporcionaste en el en el value del imput... gracias por la ayuda
html += '<td ><input   type="text"  name="item_mes[]" value="'+ $('#comboMeses option:selected').val() +'"   class="form-control item_name"  readonly /> </td>';

Comment: De nada, me alegra que te haya servido